# Python, Heroku, save Files to Local PC

Tags: python, heroku

So I know that Heroku is ephemeral and if I undestand it right it deletes a.e. a Text File that was created. So my Question is, is it possible that it just saves a Text File to my local Desktop or somewhere where I don't need to pay any money? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't at all straightforward, though it's probably technically _possible_. But it's very awkward, and do you really want your site to break if your personal machine is off or if your internet goes down? Just use a cloud service. Many of them have free tiers.

Comment: Ok, thanls @Chris